# Are there any web apps that do user stories cards?

Tags: agile, web-applications, user-stories

We do distributed agile development and could really us a solution like story cards on a wall/board, only on a webpage where you could easily drag and drop them. Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

[Trello](http://trello.com) is perfect for something like this. It's very simple, yet flexible. It's like a simpler version of PivotalTracker, mentioned above.

Answer (score 12):

Its been a while since this was asked, but the best option out there in my opinion is http://www.Sprint.ly

Really powerful. Really beautiful. Really User Story focused!

Answer (score 12):

I've used [Eidos](http://theeidos.com/). I think it's the best if you want to use in Agile project (I've used it for real 3-4 projects for the real customer). Eidos team keep developing to serve human's need in Agile project. I think they invite beta users to test now. If you have problems about co-located team, this tool is quite useful (I prefer physical thing anyway if my team is co-located)

Answer (score 5):

Me using [Eidos](http://theeidos.com/), it's easier than Jira and focus more in Agile than Trello.

Answer (score 2):

See if [scrumy](http://www.scrumy.com/) suits. 
It's a tool roughly based on scrum. You create stories from them assign tasks to a story board assign them to people. In fact it is exactly what you've asked for! :)

You can set up a free project and play around with it.

Screenshot [here](http://www.twitpic.com/m06ts/full)

Answer (score 2):

Not drag and drop, but I find basecamp very nice for agile development.

http://basecamphq.com

Answer (score 2):

For User Stories, I find [Pivotal Tracker](http://www.pivotaltracker.com) to be awesome. It automatically fits user stories into each iteration based on computed velocity. Implements just enough workflow so everyone understands what they're responsible for. And is one of the cleanest, nicest implementations I've seen. (Although AgileZen is up there too... that app is gorgeous - but I just didn't gel with it in the same way)

However the drag-drop in PivotalTracker is limited to User Story-level objects. You don't move tasks around. For a more this-sprint/iteration task board, Scrumy is probably the one to go for.

Answer (score 2):

[Mingle](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/mingle-agile-project-management) may be something to explore and see if it'll work for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

maybe a Bit oversized for your purposes, but targetprocess is a nice full blown project Management Software. It has a nice Kanban Board which fulfills your stroyboard requirement including Drag&Drop. It is free for up to 5Users.

Comment: I am checking out Target Process (3) and it is pretty incredible.

Answer (score 1):

I have used xPlanner before successfully.

http://www.xplanner.org/

Also, I have seen peole use Google Sites for similar effect. Either is drag and drop though

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Assembla tickets](http://www.assembla.com/features/ticketing) and its agile planner, it is a way to go.
Drag & Drop for:

- to make tickets and user-stories
- to sort tickets inside a milestone
- to sort user stories
- to move stories/tickets between milestones

sorting will be available on Monday(26 Oct) with next release as they promised.

Finally [distributed agile development](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/10041/Distributed-Agile-Interview-Dan-Mezick-chats-with-Andy-Singleton.aspx) is a way that Assembla is doing their client jobs.

Comment: What I dislike about Assembla "user stories" is that they are just tickets marked as "stories". There is absolutely nothing about the  these "stories" that makes them easy to create/read for customers (our customers hate to add tickets to Assembla!). The only advantage to these stories is that you can drag them around and sort them any way you want. It feels more like a late add on to their complex ticketing system, rather than a well designed user-friendly option for Agile development like Pivotal Tracker, Sprintly or even Trello.

Comment: Who can create a tool that suit everyone? ;-) You have to try some options and choose one that helps you best.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using http://www.cardmeeting.com/